# How can a single printf statement changes value in an array?

Tags: c, printf

The following program prints prime numbers between 1 and 10.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int* prime(int x,int y,int* range);

void main()
{
    int *x,s=10;
    int i=0; 
    x=prime(1,10,&s);

    for(i=0;i<s;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",x[i]);
    }


}
int* prime(int x,int y,int *range){

    int num[100],i,j,flag,inc=0;

    for(i=x;i<=y;i++)
    {
        flag=1;
        for(j=2;j<=(i/2);j++)
        {
            if(i%j == 0)
                flag=-1;
        } 
        if(flag==1)
        {

            num[inc]=i;
            inc++;
        }

    }
    *range=inc;
    //printf("$$%d$$",*range);
    return num;
}
```

the output is 
1 2 3 5 0 
in the above case, but if we remove the the comment in printf statement in prime function and give as normal printf statement the output is 
1 2 3 5 7
 How is this even possible?? What's the bug here??

The compiler i used is GCC compiler in linux platform.

Comment: Do not overlook `warning: function returns address of local variable`

Comment: I get the expected output with the same code. Its undefined behaviour because you are passing local  variable address. So at times it gives expected output and at times it does not. Undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

Your `prime()` method returns local variable `num` which is sitting on the stack, so it's not in scope (aka invalid) after the`prime()` call returns.

A couple of fixes:

- you might be able to make `num` static in `prime`
- you could dynamically allocate `num` (remember to free it)
- you could pass `num` into the `prime` method.

Answer (score 1):

Your are allocating an int array on the stack. So when you `return num;` it goes out of scope and the behaviour is undefined, because the pointer becomes invalid and you corrupt the stack.

You must allocate the array inside main and pass it to `prime()` or `malloc()` inside of `prime()` and return that, freeing it in main.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the local variable address to the main. It is not a good practice. Scope of local variable is within that module. So you can directly pass your array to the prime and work on the result directly.
**Note: Your code works perfectly too without printf in the prime.. Undefined Behaviour.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
void prime(int x,int y,int* range, int * arr);
void main()
{
    int n[10],s=10;
    int i=0; 
    prime(1,10,&s,n);
    for(i=0;i<s;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",n[i]);
    }
}
void prime(int x,int y,int *range,int *arr)
{
    int i,j,flag,inc=0;
    for(i=x;i<=y;i++)
    {
        flag=1;
        for(j=2;j<=(i/2);j++)
            if(i%j == 0) flag=-1;
        if(flag==1) *(arr+inc++)=i;
   }
   *range=inc;
}
```